# Which version control is the best for a single coder

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial

SVN, Git, or Mecurial? Which is the best for a single coder who just wants to backup his code and keep track of changes. Also I don't want to host it anywhere. I want to be able to use it locally even if I am off line and don't have internet access

Comment: My go-to is git combined with sourcetree if your on a mac..it's extremely easy to do local commits and reverts.

Comment: If you're not familiar with them, I think you'll find Mercurial the easiest. Git is complex; to use it effectively, you need to understand quite deeply how it works. Typically, Mercurial just works. SVN is a pain to work with if you need to manage the repository as well.

Comment: In isolation, Git and Mercurial might be about equally good -- but using Git gives you the opportunity to learn Git, which could be useful down the road.

Comment: @TokyoDan Im a single coder and use Mercurial, I use Git too but just for Github, svn is simple enough but sucks at merging and branching, Mercurial is the way to go, for local development you'll be more than happy, like ChrisMorgan said "it just works". BTW http://hginit.com/ is the definitive tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I just started git for a class project and found that climbing up the learning curve is entirely worth it. It's less of curve if you're already comfortable with the CLI (I was not when I started, I am now). I highly recommend reading the book/manual all the way through. It's very instructive and worth the time you will invest in it. [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book) You can use git with a remote server or local repository. Also, it's popping up in a lot of job listings it seems, so there's another reason to invest the time.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. One of the reasons I asked is because I tried using Git and could never get it right (and I read lots of tutorials). It (I) kept corrupting my repo. So I finally stopped using it. I'm not interested in learning it's intricacies as I'll never need any special thing 'down the road' as I'm retired and not looking to boost my chances of employment. I just want something simple and useful and not especially powerful. And something that is 'safe' for me to use. Sounds like Mercurial may be the best for me just because it is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

With all the requirements you described Git is your best bet by far.

- Local Repo
- Easy branch/merge
- Ability to push to remote server
- Large User community with a lot of info
- Integration into tooling

Those are just some of the benefits of Git. Ohe yeh and don't forget Github.

Comment: Mercurial matches those requirements just as well---I would say better, on the branching/merging case. But then, I'm biased (as are we all).

Comment: I use the command line with both, and Hg completion/intelligence is to die for, just love it. The Git CLI is not so friendly, at least without tuning.

Comment: With little bit of tweaking you get the autocomplete and much more ;) http://en.newinstance.it/2010/05/23/git-autocompletion-and-enhanced-bash-prompt/

Comment: @anazimok Not bash completion that's ok, I meant Hg-like "intelligent" completion. In Hg when you type `hg commit <TAB>` it completes with the changed files in your repo, pretty useful. The same when `hg add <TAB>`, it shows only the new files, and so on.